# stackoverflow list of keyboard shortcuts

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, user-interface

what are the list of rapid shortcuts that we can use when asking / answering  in SO?
I mean when I accidentally press **e** the whole question gets gray framed and i have no idea how to remove that without no editing

Comment: You can do Shift+? on any page to see the available commands for that particular page. I don't believe there is a "deselect all" command that will make the ugly border go away if you selected it by accident.

Comment: @animuson - I tried pressing `shift` and `+` at the same time but got nothing on this page. Did I do it wrong?

Comment: @TravisJ Not Shift and +, but Shift and ? (like you were trying to type a question mark).

Comment: I tried that as well, but still am not seeing any commands appear.

Comment: @TravisJ Do you have keyboard commands turned on in your preferences?

Comment: @animuson - Are those off by default? I had no idea!